# Sha or Md5 algorithm i need to encrypt and decrypt in flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, security, jsp, flex3

Hi I am developing my application in flex and JSP, so when I am passing values through HTTP Service Post method with request object but these values are tracing and modifying by testing team so I am planning to encrypt values in flex and decrypt it in jsp.so is there any algorithms like SHA or MD5 more secure algorithms, so please send any code or related links it is very useful to me. I am using like

```
httpService = new HTTPService;
httpService.request = new Object;
httpService.request.task = "doInvite";
httpService.request.email = emailInput.text;
httpService.request.firstName = firstNameInput.text;
httpService.request.lastName = lastNameInput.text;
httpService.send();
```

So is there any other way to give more secure ,please help me in this,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SHA and MD5 are one-way algorithms -- that is, you could convert `firstName` or `lastName` into a MD5 or SHA* hex string, but you would be unable to convert it back.

Comment: Retrieving and hashing password in a swf is very bad practice. Since any swf file can easily be decompiled.

Comment: @Frank - What the OP is trying to accomplish is a best practice, which is using hash encryption to not send plaintext credentials over an unencrypted wire.  The problem is, of course, that there can be no decryption....ever.  So he'll have to compare the encrypted versions on the server to authenticate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't "decrypt" MD5 or SHA1 hashes they are ONE-WAY hashes which means they are non-recoverable.

Comment: If anyone ever finds a way to decrypt these hashes, let me know. ;-) I could make some serious money with that!

Answer (score 4):

Kinda hard to read, but (as far as I could understand) you're confusing Encryption with Hashing. Neither MD5 nor SHA are encryption algorithms, they're hash algorithms:

[Hash Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

[Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider posting to a secure area of the site, i.e. over https.

Comment: Often times that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a mature Flex library that implements both the MD5 and SHA-1 hash algorythms.  So now you can use either one on the Flex side.

http://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Of course, you can't go backwards with a hash algorythm, so you'll have to compare the persisted hash with the one sent over the wire.